# Formulas to filter zero values automatically?

Tags: excel, exception

[image]

Say I have this in 'Worksheet1'

I also have 'Worksheet2' with ids and values.
I need to have ids in 'Worksheet2' but only ids 1, 3, and 5. In other words, I only want to have ids with non-zero values in the Worksheet1. How can this be done using Excel formulas?

Thank you very much.

Comment: I assume you mean you only what `IDs` where there's a value? You can copy your table, then filter out by `Values`? What have you tried

Comment: I want to achieve this without using copy/paste/filter manually. Are there any formulas I can use to achieve it?

Comment: You can use `ISBLANK` in conjunction with other functions to achieve this. Probably more complicated than its worth.

Answer (score 1):

In worksheet 2 place the following and copy down.

```
=INDEX('Worksheet1'!$A$1:$A$3,AGGREGATE(14,6,('Worksheet1'!$B$1:$B$3<>"")*ROW($B$1:$B$3),ROW(A1)),1)
```

ALTERNATIVE

you can incorporate some error catching with

```
    =IFERROR(INDEX('Worksheet1'!$A$1:$A$3,AGGREGATE(14,6,('Worksheet1'!$B$1:$B$3<>"")*ROW($B$1:$B$3),ROW(A1)),1),"")
```

Basically aggregate is finding out which rows in column B are not blank, sorting them from largest to smallest.  In the first row you will have row(A1) evaluating to 1 and as you copy down it will increase by 1.  As such it will pull the largest row then the second largest row and so on.